# Install a Windows 10 app that is no longer on the Windows Store

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

I recently purchased a new computer (Windows 10) and am trying to set it up with all the software I like, but without all the accumulated files and cruft.

One feature I made immense use of was a Windows app I found a couple of years ago, called 'Save as...'. Its function was to add an option in the 'Share' menu that allows you to simply save to the filesystem the thing being shared. It exists on my old machine (also Windows 10, upgraded from 8.1) and I use it frequently.

I cannot find it on the Windows Store anymore, however, and I would like to use it on my new Win10 computer as well. So, my question:

> Is there some way to install/sideload a Windows Store app, that can no longer be found on the Windows Store, from my old computer to my new one?

Comment: Is "copy files and registry settings that seem to be associated with the app until it works" useful here or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Run the store of Windows 10, go to "my library"](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/20361-store-my-library-install-your-apps-windows-10-a.html)

[image]

and here you see all apps assosiated to your account.

[image]

Go though the list and when you see your app, click on the download button at the end.

[image]

If you see an Exclamation mark, the app is not available for a reason. Click on it to show more details.

You can also try to use a [HTTP Proxy like Fiddler](https://superuser.com/a/493129/174557) or [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/overview/) to try to get the download link and [later sideload the APPX file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/itpro/windows/deploy/sideload-apps-in-windows-10)

Comment: My computer was not associated to an account until recently, so none of my apps are showing up in the library.

Comment: downloading an app without account is only possible since 1607 update, so if you got the app under win8.x you used an account. signin with this account in the store

Comment: You were right, I had just used a different account then. However, when I try to download it, the store tells me, "Try again later. Something happened on our end." I think this is because the app has been removed from the store.

Comment: use a proxy like fiddler or Charles to get log the network IO from store and maybe you can get the link here to download the Appx file. If this is an older Silverlight app, the XAP is DRM signed and can't be deployed/sideloaded.

Comment: What precisely am I looking for? I have found a 12 character alphanumeric that appears to correspond to the application, but I don't know how to use it, nor how to tell if this is an older Silverlight app as you mentioned.

Comment: look at this post: http://superuser.com/a/493129/174557

Comment: At this point I gave up and found an alternative (paid) option to the missing app, but if you want to add some of this relevant info to your answer I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: what should I add?

Comment: That if the app cannot download normally because it is no longer on the Windows Store, then it might be possible to sniff Store's traffic with something like fiddler and get a download link out in some cases---that was my problem, after all.

Comment: ok, I added this to the answer