# How do I download APPX packages for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Microsoft account. I wish to download appx packages for my tablet and then install them manually. I don't want to associate my account. The tablet is the only Win10 PC I can use, so I can't install them on another and then copy it.

Comment: Open the Powershell as an administrator, type or paste the following code and Enter 
*Get-AppxPackage -allusers | Select Name, PackageFullName*
below show you the list of default apps and find the app you want to reinstall in the list. After you highlight this string, press Enter or Ctrl + C to copy and type the following code on the PowerShell, replacing PackageFullName with the string you just copied (just press Ctrl + V and hit Enter.
*Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PackageCodeName\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode*
Open the Start menu and see the app.

Comment: @vembutech I am trying to get the `appx` file, I already know how to install it once I have it but I can't get the `appx` from Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a proxy such as fiddler to sniff Store traffic and capture the appx packages.

This has been discussed here:

- [How to download an app from the window 10 store to sideload](https://superuser.com/questions/1196609/how-to-download-an-app-from-the-window-10-store-to-sideload)
- [Install a Windows 10 app that is no longer on the Windows Store](https://superuser.com/questions/1159730/install-a-windows-10-app-that-is-no-longer-on-the-windows-store)

Comment: It sucks there is no simpler way. For it to work, you also need a M$ account and also need to allow several applications through firewall