# How to download an app from the window 10 store to sideload

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

I'd like to download a Windows 10 store app to sideload onto a Windows 10 PC that's not on the internet.  I have sideloading enabled on the Windows 10 PC that's not on the internet.  Is it possible to just download a package from the Windows 10 store?

Thanks

Comment: So your question is, is it possible to side-load a application thats been published to the store application, yes, but it requires you build an system image which includes the application which doesn't apply to your case

Comment: use [fiddler](https://superuser.com/a/493129/174557) or any other Proxy tool to snif the Store activity to get the download links of the appx files. Old Windows 8 Apps XAP files from Stpre are encrypted and can't be sideloaded

Comment: I'm familiar with fiddler.  I hadn't thought of using it.  I'll give it a shot.